# Get visibility of product in product list

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-list, list.phtml

Within a product list, I would like to access

```
$product->getVisibility()
```

for each product of the collection. However, this is always `null` instead of either of the 4 states. I have already added

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_product">
        <attribute name="visibility" />
    </group>
</config>
```

to the `app/code/<vendor>/<module>/etc/catalog_attributes.xml`. While this works fine for other custom properties of the products, it does not seem to have any affect on the `visibility` property - and I have no idea why.

Magento `2.3.2`

Comment: try this $product->getAttributeText('visibility');

Comment: This is also `null`.

Comment: how to get product collection by object manager or custom module..?

Comment: if you are using custom module then you should need to use like this in __construct  
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,   $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;  then fetch like this $this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds()

Comment: It is the regular product list from `magento/module-catalog`, no custom module.

Comment: I think for show product visibility on product listing page you should need to load custom product collection because "getLoadedProductCollection" data collection will not get visibility filed, it's already filtered by "Catalog, Search" attributed collection data. You need to load you custom product collection to show visibility value.

Comment: <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->load(); 
    foreach ($collection as $product) { 
    echo $product->getAttributeText('visibility') . '<br />';
    echo $product->getName() . '<br />';
}
?>

Comment: I see. But shouldn't the `catalog_attributes.xml` definition still apply, no matter if the list is already filtered by visibility?